# How do i display data from a dataframe in tkinter treeview?

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I'm using the following code to display data from a pandas dataframe in a tkinter treeview:

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk

mywin=Tk()
mywin.geometry('300x300')

df=pd.read_csv('<filepath of csv file>')
df_list=list(df.columns.values)
df_rset=df.to_numpy().tolist()
df_tree=ttk.Treeview(mywin,columns=df_list).pack()
                                     
for i in df_list:
    df_tree.column(i,width=100,anchor='c')
    df_tree.heading(i,text=i)
for dt in df_rset:
    v=[r for r in dt]
    df_tree.insert('','end',iid=v[0], values=v)

mywin.mainloop()
```

But this give me an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'column'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
df_tree=ttk.Treeview(mywin,columns=df_list)
df_tree.pack()
```